# PsShutdown in Task Scheduler of Windows 7

Tags: uac, windows-task-scheduler

I try to use [PsShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) to schedule late sleep, restart and etc on Windows 7 machine.

In order to run the command manually I have to open the command window as Administrator first. So how can I do it in `Task Scheduler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I run command as Administrator in the Task Scheduler?

In the "Create Task" > "General" dialog you have the option to select the user account used to run the task ("Change User or Group").

You may also want to enable "Run with highest privileges".

---

#### Creating a Task with the Details View

> Once you already know what you are doing, there’s no reason to go through a wizard to create a new task (unless you really like them). Instead, you can just create a new task and fill out the sections with the settings that you want – and naturally, there are more settings available this way.
>
> [image]
>
> **User account allows you to specify which user this task is going to run as.** If you want the task to interact with the desktop, you’re
> going to probably want to use your own user account, which is the
> default. If you specify the SYSTEM account, you won’t want to save a
> password.

...

> **Run with highest privileges – this option essentially gives the task administrator privileges the same way the User Account Control (UAC) prompt would do it.** If you plan to use this for administrative purposes, you will probably want to enable this option.

Source [Using Task Scheduler to Run Processes Later](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/all/)

Comment: He may have to select Run with Highest privileges

Comment: It works, the "highest privileges" is the right answer.